# Android : Pass string from xml into string array

Tags: android, string, android-xml

I need to pass a string that i have created in strings.xml to java class that has a string array method. I have created the string but don't know how to pass it into the array

strings.xml

```
<string name = "bank">
    <b>Bank</b>
</string>
```

Facilityadapter.java

```
public String[] mThumbNames = {
       getResources().getStringArray(R.string.bank),
        "Hostel",
        "GYM",
        "Library",
        "Sports",
        "Guest House"

};
```

Comment: You cannot access getResources before the Activity has initialised. You'll want to pull in the bank string in/after your onCreate method has run

Comment: bank is not a string array resource, it is a string resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class FacilityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] mThumbNames;

    public FacilityAdapter(Context c){
        mThumbNames = new String[] {c.getString(R.string.bank), "Hostel", "GYM"};
    }

    //...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the complete code is like this

```
    public class FacilityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.bank, R.drawable.girlshostel,
            R.drawable.gym , R.drawable.library,
            R.drawable.sports , R.drawable.guesthouse

    };

    public String[] mThumbNames = new String[]{
            getResources().getStringArray(R.string.bank)[0],
            "GirlsHostel",
            "GYM",
            "<u>Library</u>",
            "Sports",
            "Guest House"

    };



    // Constructor
    public FacilityAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View gridView;
        gridView = new View(mContext);



        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getResources().getString(R.string.bank)
```

also, as biddulph.r says, do this after `onCreate` method